# Server-side support for seeking through videos delivered via HTML 5 <video> tags

Tags: c#, .net, html, html5-video

I have a web application running on a custom-built web server that downloads torrents. I'd like to offer the ability to stream the torrents to the user's browser. How do I handle seeking? How does the browser tell the server that it'd like to seek?

If the server makes the request for some video, do I simply start pushing the video down the response stream, and it'll stream it? How does the browser handle the open stream when it needs to seek?

Something perhaps of note: I won't have the entire video file on the server when the user starts streaming.

Comment: Dun dun dun, I know some experts will probably have the answer off the bat, but wouldn't some snooping of the requests be a good place to start?

Comment: I suppose. I would presume this is documented somewhere, so I'd rather not reverse engineer it and perhaps get something wrong. I spent a lot of time reading on MDN, though, and found nothing.